# Adapting to the dimensionality curse: current state-of-the-art

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics

Quantum mechanics suffers from a dimensionality curse due to the Hilbert space dimension depending exponentially on the number of degrees of freedom (DoF). I thought the largest number of *continuous* DoFs treated by a numerical solution of the time-dependent Schroedinger equation was 4, but then I found [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/29/2/002) that solves it for 5, and is from the early 1990s. I then noticed I have no idea of how much progress was made in this field. Did we go much further than that?

**P.S.:** Yes, continuous degrees of freedom are approximated as discrete in computations, but this discretization is not theoretical and is only relevant for convergence. I am obviously assuming converged results.

Comment: Are you looking for info about general solvers that take arbitrary Hamiltonians, or specialized ones that solve a certain class of problems?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I am not looking for solvers at all, nor for (theoretically) discrete systems. I am looking for papers solving the time-dependent Schroedinger equation numerically, without approximations, for the highest possible number of degrees of freedom. Note that it's important that the degrees of freedom are continuous, otherwise the answer is essentially millions (quantum-many body stuff).

Comment: Okay, when I wrote "solver" I meant something that can be used for "solving the time-dependent Schroedinger equation numerically" ;) But the specification to continuous DoFs is essential, you should probably add it to the question.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer It is, you're totally right. Just did it.

Comment: Related (but currently closed): [For how many particles can we solve the Schrödinger equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669883)